# Reading data from .raw file in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

I'm trying plot graphs using .raw files containing sets of y coordinates in Mathematica. I'm unsure what to type to actually refer to the data in the files directly - I'm currently using 'data' and am unsure if this is correct.

This is the code I have:

```
    SetDirectory[$HomeDirectory <> "/Documents/Project/Work/Output"]
    alldirs = FileNames["deBB-*"]
    alllocdata = {};
    Do[
       SetDirectory["./" <> alldirs[[idir]]];
       Print["--- working on " <> (dirname = alldirs[[idir]])];
       allfiles = FileNames["T-*.raw"];
       Do[
          Print["   --- working on " <> (filename = allfiles[[ifile]])];
          ReadList[filename, Number];
          AppendTo[alllocdata, data];
          Print[ListPlot[data, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 2000}, 
          DataRange -> {0, 10000},
          AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]], {ifile, Length[allfiles]}
       ];
       SetDirectory[ParentDirectory[]],
       {idir, Length[alldirs]}
    ]
```

I've been getting this error:

```
    ListPlot::lpn: data is not a list of numbers or pairs of numbers. >>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a sample of the first few entries in one set of `data`?

Comment: For example one is:

702.00000
704.00000
706.00000
708.00000
....

and continues for 10000 results.

Comment: So it looks like `data = {702.00000,704.00000,706.00000,708.00000}` or `data =  "702.00000 704.00000 706.00000 708.00000"`?

Comment: data = "702.00000 704.00000 706.00000 708.00000", a series of numbers each separated by a space.

Comment: You may be interested to know that there is also a [Mathematica-specific StackExchange site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

One issue from your code is that you never got around to assigning the variable 'data'.  What you probably meant was

```
data = ReadList[filename, Number];
```

A second issue is `ReadList`.  This is pretty old-school, although it will work, and (roughly 10x) faster than Import.  Because you're reading the numbers as `Number` (...) you don't need to convert them form strings.

A third issue is `AppendTo`.  This command is notoriously slow.  I'd suggest an indexed approach.  Something like

```
basdir = "~/parentdir";
SetDirectory[basdir];
alldir = FileNames["deBB-*"];
alldir = Select[alldir, DirectoryQ[#] &] (* directories only *);
alldat = Range[Length@alldir];
(
    SetDirectory[cdir = StringJoin[basdir, "/", alldir[[#]]]];
    Print["Working in ", cdir];
    allfil = FileNames["T-*.raw"];
    alldat[[#]] = Range[Length@allfil];
    tmpdat = Import[allfil[[#]], "Table"] & /@ Range[Length@allfil];
    alldat[[#]] = tmpdat;
    Print@ListPlot[tmpdat[[#]], PlotLabel -> allfil[[#]]] & /@ 
     Range[Length@allfil];
    ) & /@ Range[Length@alldir];
```

should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, the `data` is actually a `String`, rather than a numeric quantity.

```
data = "702.00000 704.00000 706.00000 708.00000"
```

This can be seen by looking at the `Head[data]` which outputs `String`.

To parse it, simply use

```
ToExpression@StringSplit@data
```

instead of `data` in your `ListPlot`:

```
ListPlot[ToExpression@StringSplit@data, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {0, 2000}, 
 DataRange -> {0, 10000}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]